# Singular or plural verb after a list of single items/activities?

Tags: conjugations

In the following sentence, which one is correct? "requires" or "require"?

> Reading all recent findings, relating them together, and finally drawing a conclusion from them **require(s)** dedication and discipline.

Although "require(s)" refer to all activities of "reading", "relating", and "drawing", in my mother language the singular form of the verb is correct. Hence I was wondering if the same goes for English.

Answer (score -2):

Is it your sentence?
As constructed, the verb should be "require" because its subject is a series of several things, but it's going to sound wrong.

To get the verb to sound right, you might use a dummy pronoun "it", which is taken as singular:

> It requires dedication and discipline to collect all recent findings, correlate them, and draw a conclusion from them.

Comment: Yes it is my sentence. Why is it going to sound wrong?  "Reading all recent findings, relating them together, and finally drawing a conclusion from them" is subject of the sentence, "require" is the verb, "dedication and discipline" is the object.

Comment: It may sound wrong because the series is long and consists of dissimilar (non-parallel) terms; that may make the last item, "drawing....", feel like a singular subject.

Comment: So it is grammatically correct but ambiguous?

Comment: It's grammatically correct and not ambiguous. It may just be a little hard to digest.

Comment: I don't think *because its subject is a series of several things* justifies saying *the verb should be (plural) "require"*. I can't imagine any context where anyone would ever say/write *Reading and correcting the text **were** challenging*, and structurally speaking that's pretty much the same as OP's example.

Comment: ...to my mind, If ***There is/are*** comes before a list, the plurality usually agrees with the ***first*** item in the list, not the fact that there are multiple items in the list *(There **is** an apple and some grapes on the table)*. And it's usually the same when the verb comes *after* the list - where the verb tends to agree with the ***last*** item in the list *(An apple and some grapes **are** on the table)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I might say "There's an apple and some oranges...", but if I expanded it, I wouldn't say "There is...", I would say "There are..." Also, I don't think I would say "Reading and correcting the text was..."

Comment: I don't think we can be too dogmatic about *either* position here, because there's considerable variation between different speakers. I'm slightly inclined to think that AmE speakers in general are more likely to endorse stricter / simpler principles in such contexts. Noting your final comment, I suppose you'd balk at *Reading and correcting the text **was** time-consuming* in *any* context. To me, the singular verb is much more natural there, but if I heard ***...were** time-consuming*, I'd accept it as deliberately emphasising *two separate tasks* (which is odd, since they're "concurrent").

Comment: It's not hard and fast, and in complex expressions, whether a singular or plural verb sounds right can be affected by what's closest to the verb.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty based on this answer [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390032/should-i-use-was-or-were-in-this-sentence-or-when-i-list-items] your answer seems wrong. I am confused.

Comment: @alireza I disagree with that answer. Some lists can be seen as a singular thing. I don't think that's true of your list.